# Have I installed a package successfully from source?

Tags: software-installation

I try to install [the latest stable psensor version](http://wpitchoune.net/psensor/files/psensor-last-stable.tar.gz) (psensor-1.0.4) from source on ubuntu 12.04. After running `./configure`, `make` and either `make install` or `checkinstall`, there is no command `psensor`.

```
$ psensor
The program 'psensor' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install psensor
```

So i wonder if I compile the code successfully? Here are [the output of the `./configure` to stdout](http://pastebin.com/8b8AZHdk), [the output of `make` to stdout](http://pastebin.com/YvZc8vhM), and [the output of `make install`](http://pastebin.com/kYFtWXA1). Also the output of `./configure` to stderr is

```
configure: WARNING: "gtk missing psensor will not be built"
configure: WARNING: "gconf2 missing psensor will not be built"
configure: WARNING: "Library atasmart not present"
configure: WARNING: "Desktop notification disabled"
configure: WARNING: AppIndicator 3-0.1 not present"
configure: WARNING: AppIndicator 0.2.9 not present"
configure: WARNING: "AppIndicator > 0.2.9 not present"
configure: WARNING: "Remote monitoring disabled
configure: WARNING: "json-c missing"
configure: WARNING: "json0 missing"
configure: WARNING: Unity not present
configure: WARNING: "libmicrohttpd not present
configure: WARNING: "gtop not present
```

But my ubuntu 12.04 is updated, and I don't quite understand why things like `Unity`  not present.

---

If I run `check install`, [the output](http://pastebin.com/9CqFGgAM) of `locate psensor | grep -i usr` seems there is no executable generated or copied to a system directory.

If I run `make install`, [The output of `sudo find psensor /|grep psensor`](http://pastebin.com/wggdiPHg) 
shows the remaining files of the other older Ubuntu versions of psensor I have tried and uninstalled.

---

After installing the packages reported as missing by `./configure`, now the list is reduced to

```
configure: WARNING: "Desktop notification disabled"
configure: WARNING: "Remote monitoring disabled
configure: WARNING: "json-c missing"
```

http://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/json-c seems to say that `json-c` is in `libjson0-dev` which I have installed, but `./configure` still says `json-c` is missing.

Originally, I haven't installed any packages missing said by ./configure, why I could still `make` and `make install` without given errors?

Comment: is it in your path?

Comment: It should be, but I think it isn't. check out the output of `locate psensor | grep usr` in my post.

Comment: then use `sudo find psensor /|grep psensor`

Comment: use the find command with the `/` to look through the whole filesystem to locate `psensor`

Comment: See the end of my post.

Comment: maybe it didnt uninstall all the way...uninstall both and try to do a fresh install of the latest one

Comment: I don't think you have built all the components (due to missing dependencies) - try installing the `libgtk2.0-dev` and `libgconf2-dev` packages and then repeating the `./configure`, `make`, `make install` steps.

Comment: @steeldriver: thanks. just did it. (1) https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/json-c seems to say that `json-c` is in `libjson0-dev` which I also installed, but `./configure` still says `json-c` is missing. (2) Before installed any packages missing said by `./configure`, why I could still `make` and `make install` without given errors? See the outputs in my post.

Comment: psensor is in Debian. I recommend a backport, if the version in your release is not good enough for you.